# No Screen Sharing option on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: remote-desktop, desktop-sharing

I need to allow screen sharing on my machine. In setteings>sharing there is no option of screen sharing at all. Vino is installed. I have looked in gdm3 and lightdm but it is the same.  I have installed dconf-editor but I do not know which is the correct setting in  /org/gnome/desktop/remote-access/ to allow screen sharing.
The require-encryption is off.
Thank you

Comment: What happens if you start vino-server directly?

Comment: Typing `vino-server` results in `command not found`.

Comment: `/usr/local/lib/vino/vino-server` results in `X11 is not detected`

Comment: Are you calling vino-server from within a terminal in the gui? Do you have Wayland installed or X11? What happens if you open the terminal and `echo $DISPLAY; xauth list`?

Comment: `:0
EVOWEW/unix:  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  9e3783055d740e5d32bbc8128a6eeecd
#ffff#45564f574557#:  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  9e3783055d740e5d32bbc8128a6eeecd`

Comment: The above comment is a result of `echo $DISPLAY; xauth list` . I use vino-server from terminal. I am logging into "Ubuntu" and not "Ubuntu Wayland" . X11 and Walyland are installed.

Comment: For me works without problems. However, I'm using GNOME Flashback and not GNOME Shell. After installing Vino an icon to start it appeared in the menu. I just click it (after setting parameters in dconf, of course) and it works. Try to find if you don't also have it somewhere in applications menu.

Comment: I do not find Vino in the menu, how do you use GNOME flashback?

Answer (score 8):

I also had faced this issue. I just installed vino and it solved my problem

```
sudo apt install vino
```

Now I can see Screen Sharing option in Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS

Comment: This is documented on the ubuntu website: add the package vino for the Screen Sharing option to appear. Maybe add the link to your answer? https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sharing-desktop.html.en

Comment: I already have `vino` and can't see this option in the settings. This is still a basic issue.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling Ubuntu 20.04 from USB drive solved the problem. Probably some tweak I did after installation caused this option to disappear.